# How would I create an custom allocator for a nested hashmap that can be memcopied?

Tags: c

I want to create deep copies of nested hashmaps cheaply and easily. This is for parallelism and multithreading.

I want to be capable of `memcpy`ing a hashmap and then deep clone the contents of the hashmap.

I think I can do this with a custom allocator.

How should I design the allocator and arrange the memory? I feel I should use indexes rather than pointers?

I wrote this simplistic hashmap https://github.com/samsquire/contiguous-hashmap that allocates a contiguous array of values. But I wondering how to make a single memory structure contain nested hashmaps too.

The nested hashmaps are hashmaps inside hashmaps.

Comment: Make the hash map a flat array, not an array of pointers. Then you can easily memcpy it.

Comment: What about nested hashmaps? Could I have a formula for child elements? Similar to a binary heap?

Comment: Yeah, just hash the entire combine key, rather than using nested maps.

Comment: Nesting is just a type of indexing strategy.